# How to place relative pronoun correctly?

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

**The Thames is a beautiful river. It flows through London**

Combining these two sentences with relative pronoun:

**(1) The Thames is a beautiful river, which flows through London.**

or

**(2) The Thames, which flows through London, is a beautiful river.**

or

**(3) The Thames, which is a beautiful river, flows through London.**

Are the three options above (1), (2) and (3) both grammatically correct? If this is the case, which one sounds more natural than the other?

Your help is precious. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'Both' is used about **two** things only. The three options are **all** grammatically correct, and none sounds more 'natural' than the others.

Comment: I don't like the comma in 1, but otherwise agree. Which you choose depends on your focus: it's beauty or location.

Comment: @StuartF - Its beauty or location?

Comment: I think that even fanatical lovers of London might hesitate to call the Thames 'beautiful'.

Comment: In (1) I would use "that" instead of "which" and omit the comma.

Answer (score 1):

All are grammatical. The difference is whether your primary point is that the Thames is a beautiful river (1 and 2), or that it flows through London (3).

There is no difference in meaning between 1 and 2, but what comes at the end of the sentence tends to have some prominence, so they are different in that respect.